# CakePHP different passwords using AuthComponent

Tags: php, cakephp, hash, xdebug

Using AuthComponent i'm having trouble with passwords. One in debugging displays diffent than in saved in database.

1. 1 password saved in Database :

> d074dc36936aeb8fdc709112969425f71eedc694

1. 2.password debuged in Controller

> aa979656c76b9974130ad2698a221d4dd93ca4ca
>   
>   User Model

```
<?php
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
class User extends AppModel {

public $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
        'rule' => array('between', 3, 32),
        'required' => true,
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'message' => 'Podaj poprawne imię!'
    ),
    'last_name' => array(
        'rule' => array('between', 3, 32),
        'required' => true,
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'message' => 'Podaj poprawne nazwisko!'
    ),
    'password' => array(
        'rule' => array('minLength', 6),
        'required' => true,
        'message' => 'Hasło powinno mieć minimum 6 znaków!'
    ),
    're_password' => array(
        'rule' => 'equalToPassword',
        'required' => true,
        'on' => 'create',
        'message' => 'Hasła nie są identyczne!'
    )
);

public function equalToPassword() {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password']) && isset($this->data[$this->alias]['re_password'])) {
        return $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] == $this->data[$this->alias]['re_password'];
    }
}

public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
  if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
    $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
 }
 return true;
}

}
```

UsersController

```
<?php

class UsersController extends AppController {

public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('admin_login', 'admin_logout','admin_add');
}
public function login()
{
    $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'admin_login'));
}
public function admin_login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        debug(AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']));
        //$this->request->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->request->data['User']['password']);
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}

public function admin_logout() {
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}

public function admin_add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        //$this->request->data['User']['craeted'] ;
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Users has been created!'));
            return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'admin_index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('User can not be save!'));
    }
}
```

add.ctp

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Form->create('User'); 
    echo $this->Form->input('name',array('label'=>'imię/login','class'=>'form-control'));
    echo $this->Form->input('last_name',array('label'=>'nazwisko','class'=>'form-control'));
    echo $this->Form->input('password',array('label'=>'hasło','class'=>'form-control'));
    echo $this->Form->input('re_password',array('label'=>'powtórz hasło','class'=>'form-control'));
    echo $this->Form->input('role',array('options'=>array('admin'=>'Admin','user'=>'Bez praw')));
    echo $this->Form->submit('Zapisz',array('class'=>'btn btn-info'));
    echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

login.ctp

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Form->create('User'); 
    echo $this->Form->input('name',array('label'=>'imię/login','class'=>'form-control'));
    echo $this->Form->input('password',array('label'=>'hasło','class'=>'form-control'));
    echo $this->Form->submit('Login',array('class'=>'btn btn-info'));
    echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to hash the password as cake does it for you

so when you do

```
$this->request->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->request->data['User']['password'])
```

you're hashing a password that will be automatically hashed by cake on save or when checking the user for login.

Also: `AuthComponent::password` is deprecated since 2.4

see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords

Comment: i changed this AuthComponent as You said to this tutorial http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

btu my passwords are still different and i can't log in. I'm working on int since yesterday and it's very frustraiting...

Comment: if you have hashed the password on save then the password have been hashed two times. I suggest to save again the password or change them using letting cake hashing them for you if you don't have any other need

Comment: i cleared my CakePHP cache and it finally works without changing anything